# The momentum space volume element

Tags: classical-mechanics, particle-physics, statistical-mechanics, phase-space

I am reading a paper in which the following relations is used :

The momentum space volume element can be written as $$d^3p_1 d^3 p_2 =4 \pi p_1 E_1 dE_1 4 \pi p_2 E_2 dE_2 \frac{d (cos \theta)}{2}$$
where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are the three-momenta and $E_1$ , $E_2$ are the energies of the colliding particles in the cosmic comoving frame and $\theta$  is the angle between $p_1$ and $p_2$. And also the energy momentum relation is used that is $E^2 -p^2=m^2$, where $c=1$ in natural units.

I have done lot of work but could not figure it out. I request you , kindly help me because this looks very trivial but I am unable to figure it out. Kindly help.
One way I am thinking is through the change of variables from $p1,p2$ to $E1,E2,\theta$, and then to multiply by suitable Jacobian.In that case, I am unable to figure out the Jacobian.

If you want to see it then kindly refer to
https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(91)90438-4
equation (3.2)

Comment: $\theta$ seems to be the angle formed between the directions of the two particles, but can you define it in your question? It seems like a change of variables to spherical coordinates where you "integrate out" the angular variables. Also, do you know which relationship between the energy and the magnitude of the momenta are they using ($E_i=E_i(p_i)$)? this depends on whether you treat the relativistic case or not.

Comment: $\theta$ is the angle between $p_1$ and $p_2$. And they are using the relativistic relation between Energy and momentum for sure.

Comment: $(E_1+E_2)^2 -(p_1+p_2)^2=4m^2$ This relation is being used.

Comment: Is your equation dimensionally sound?

Comment: @CosmasZachos . Yes , but that is the equation what is mentioned in the paper that I have mentioned in the post.

Comment: They’ve skipped two Es…

Comment: Yes there has to be 2 such factors of E . But , apart from that how do one obtain the $dcos\theta /2 $ term?